# MPII pose estimation dataset: visibility flag not present

Tags: dataset, kaggle, pose-estimation, pose

From the [MPII Dataset Download page](http://human-pose.mpi-inf.mpg.de/#download) we can see that keypoints have a visibility flag called `is_visible`. This flag indicates if the joint is visible (ocluded) or not. It can take values 0 (not visible) or 1 (visible). However, while exploring the dataset I have found two other scenarios for the state of a keypoint:

- Keypoint not in the list: It seems that this means the keypoint is not in the image (not ocluded, but outside of the image).
- Not present: the `is_visible` flag is just not there, but just an empty array. If I print the point object's `__dict__` attribute I get:

```
    {'_fieldnames': ['id', 'x', 'y', 'is_visible'],
     'id': array([[8]], dtype=uint8),
     'x': array([[682]], dtype=uint16),
     'y': array([[256]], dtype=uint16),
     'is_visible': array([], shape=(0, 0), dtype=uint8)}
```

My question is: Can I safely assume that a not present `is_visible` flag means the same as a False Flag?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like empty `is_visible` flags are refering to visible, head points instead. I've plotted here these points in green, while visible and not visible are in red and black, respectively. I don't know the reason behind it though.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this is very useful. so to sum it up, if the joint is missing from the joint list, it's invisible. if is_visible is empty or 1, then it's visible. if it's 0, then it's just occluded.